# How to turn off Rails caching during development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, static-files

I'm on Rails 5.2.2 and I'm building a web app that uses some static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that I'm serving from inside of the `public` directory. Much of the time when I update a file it doesn't update in my browser when I refresh, but if I go into private browsing it works -- until it caches again and then I need to open a new private window.

How can I turn off caching for file in the `public` folder? Or if it's easier, how can I turn off all caching during development?

This is what my `development.rb` looks like. I tried commenting out the entire `if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?` block but that didn't do anything.

I'm also open to installing a gem to solve this if it can't be fixed with a setting.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options)
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Highlight code that triggered database queries in logs.
  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  # Add devide default mailer url
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }


  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: so, it looks like your browser is caching the files ?, just hard reload a page and the request will load the files again. In a Mac you do it with shift + command + r.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not rails who caches, it's your browser.

Either you explicitly set

```
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => "no-cache"
}
```

(and clean your browser cache, who has all old and valid versions of your files), or you disable browser cache completely.

Comment: Thanks @rewritten, seems like this works but I'm going to mess with it for a few minutes before accepting this answer. I've mostly worked with node in the past and haven't had this issue there. Just to clarify, this is because Rails sends headers along with public files to the browser telling it to cache the response?

Comment: If the server sends no header, then the browser is free to choose. It does not depend on it being rails. When you worked with node, you probably had some webpack-based asset server that managed it for you, even pushing and hot-reloading assets. With rails, if you use a recent webpacker, it should behave the same way, but sprocket is older and does not manage the cache headers for you.

Comment: Additionally, chrome dev tools include a "disable cache" option under the network tab. I believe it only applies while dev tools are open. Personally, I'd prefer this solution, so I don't have to change the server code.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with "or you disable browser cache completely" @kennycok